# Hibernate's nullable = false not working in all cases

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I have the following class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

    private Long userID;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    public Long getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean isActive;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;


    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar lastLoggedIn;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar createdDate;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Calendar getLastLoggedIn() {
        return lastLoggedIn;
    }

    public void setLastLoggedIn(Calendar lastLoggedIn) {
        this.lastLoggedIn = lastLoggedIn;
    }

    public Calendar getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Calendar createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public void setUserID(Long userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public User(Long userID, String email, String password, Calendar lastLoggedIn, Calendar createdDate, Integer version) {

    }

    // No argument constructor
    public User() {}
}
```

When I run my application, Hibernate loads the configuration and creates the table for Users. I'm using Postgresql. This is the SQL statement being generated (logged by hibernate):

```
Hibernate: create table USERS 
           (userID int8 not null, active boolean not null, createdDate timestamp, 
            email varchar(255), lastLoggedIn timestamp, 
            password varchar(255), version int4, primary key (userID))
```

Why is it that a boolean is created as not null and a String/Timestamp is not? I won't there to be an exception if you try to insert a User without an email or password, but with this generated schema it won't. Is there another way to force Hibernate to create the field as not nullable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From  [5.1.4.1.2. Access type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-property) :

> By default the access type of a class hierarchy is defined by the
>   position of the @Id or @EmbeddedId annotations. If these annotations
>   are on a field, then only fields are considered for persistence and
>   the state is accessed via the field. If there annotations are on a
>   getter, then only the getters are considered for persistence and the
>   state is accessed via the getter/setter.

As you annotate `@Id` on the getter , you are using property access. So , hibernate will ignore all mapping annotations marked on the fields and only use annotations on getters to generate DDL . Because there are no annotations on getters , default settings are used .

You should get your desired result if you change to annotate `@Id` on the `userID` instead of `getUserID()`